# Clearer expression of "pointing to the moon" as metaphor for miscommunication

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> "While I was trying to show him the moon with my finger, he wrote hundreds of thousands of essays and term papers in the description of my finger."

Is there a better way to convey clearly this message that the person you are talking to doesn't really understand what you are talking about. Please note that I want to use "moon" metaphorically. So it shouldn't be taken literally.

Comment: When I pointed at the moon he only saw my finger.

Comment: Still Not Satisfied.I mean analyzing the pointer is pointless.

Comment: Does it have to include “moon” and “finger”?

Comment: @user2684291:yes

Comment: “He pondered the finger instead of the Moon it was pointing at.”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zen Buddhism is all over the finger and the moon. Just do an Internet search for 'finger moon zen'. You'll get a popular Zen quote and many restatements of the quote.

> “All instruction is but a finger pointing to the moon; and those whose gaze is fixed upon the pointer will never see beyond. Even let him catch sight of the moon, and still he cannot see its beauty.”
>   — Zen Saying
>
> The finger can point to the moon's location. However, the finger is not the moon. To look at the moon, it is necessary to gaze beyond the finger, right?"
>
> One of the most used metaphors in Buddhism (especially Zen Buddhism) is that of the finger and the moon. It warns against mistaking the finger which points to the moon...

And so on, and so forth... In fact, because of your choice of the words *finger* and *moon*, I am thinking Zen has something to do with your question.

Comment: @Mia you're very welcome